# Is there a word for the form of a word that means "pertaining to"?

Tags: vocabulary

For the sake of this question, let's call types of words forms "onym"s, as in "demonym" or "retronym". (Note: I don't know the word for those kinds of words, either.)

I'm looking for the "onym" that means "pertaining to".

For example, literally is the __onym of literal.  Functional is the __onym of function.

Does such a word exist?

Edit:  Sorry, it doesn't actually have to end in "nym", I'm just not very good at articulating this sort of thing.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't know the answer (yet), but I do know that the suffix is *-onym*, not *\*-nym*, from Greek *onoma/onuma* "name, noun".

Comment: In linguistics, it is called a *derivative*. I don't know why you think there should be a *nym-word* for it.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the closest word that goes in that blank is "adjectival", though of course you have to get rid of the "-nym" suffix.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

If you insist on the word terminating in "onym" then no - it doesn't exist.

The reason is that the suffix 'onym' comes from the Greek word "onama", which means "name". For example

'synonym' means 'a name that has the same function (as another name)'.

There is no reason for *"literally is the __onym of literal"* to have a solution because there is no relevance of the suffix 'nym' to relating parts of speech.